# Api-Platform with multiple data sources, how to map entity with Doctrine OR ElasticSearch

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Api-Platform: v2.5.6, Symfony: v4.4.11

I am building an API with multiple DataSource. For now, one from Postgres, another from ElasticSearch.

For example, I have an `Organization` entity from `postgres` and a `Stats` entity from ElasticSearch.

If ElasticSearch service isn't reachable, I would like the `/organizations` route to be ok because they don't need ElasticSearch to work.

For now I get `"No alive nodes found in your cluster"` because it tries to communicate with the `"/_cat/indices/organization"` route of ElasticSearch.

This dives me to a questions, if it tries everytime to communicate to both ElasticSearch and Postgres, **whatever the entity**.

How to prevent this, for example can I say that an entity is mapped with a DataSource and not another ?

Or maybe at least set a priority ?

My `app/config/packages/api_platform.yaml`

```
api_platform:
    allow_plain_identifiers: true
    title: HeyAPI Documentation
    version: 2.0.0
    formats:
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
        json: ['application/json']
        graphql: ['application/graphql'] #https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request

    mapping:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/config/api_platform'

    patch_formats:
        json: ['application/merge-patch+json']

    elasticsearch:
        hosts: ['%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%']

    swagger:
        versions: [3]
        api_keys:
            Bearer:
                name: Authorization
                type: header
```

Comment: Can you share your api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml i look this link :  https://api-platform.com/docs/core/elasticsearch/

Comment: maybe i'm wrong but this link : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/elasticsearch/#creating-custom-mapping you can include entity with elastic search only.

Comment: @GaryHoubre Unfortunatelly not
This is to define how the fields are mapped.
If I put the entity only here (and not in `mapping.paths`), it's not used by ApiPlatform.
If I put in both, I have the same behaviour as described.

Comment: @BastienSander Have you found a solution to have Doctrine entities and ES works together ?

Comment: It works well, but I can't find a way to tell which is the priority.
Here you can find some help : https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1641